# How can I tell if the script is being run as super user?

Tags: linux, lua

I've written a fan control script in Lua, and I'm running Linux. The fan control needs to write to /sys/ so I need to be super user.

I want to inform the user if they are NOT super user. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only certain test is to check whether the POSIX [geteuid() call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/geteuid.html) returns zero.

For this you may have to use a Lua library like [luaposix](http://luaforge.net/projects/luaposix/).

Or you can shell out and run `id -u` to see if it outputs `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's Linux, you can try this, which is stock Lua and does not need additional libraries:

```
function running_as_root()
  local f=io.open"/root"
  if f==nil then return false else io.close(f) return true end
end
```

But why not just try to write to /sys/ and report failure if that happens?

Comment: It seems messy to me to try to perform io, and if it fails then they're not root. I was looking for something less hacky if you get me. But valid suggestion so a +1 to you :)

Comment: Not every Linux system has a "/root" directory.

Comment: But they do have "/". "/bin" or "/usr" would probably be just as good. But I agree with lhf here. Just go do the planned IO, and fail with a polite message about needing to be root when it fails.

Answer (score 0):

best thing to do is just report failure: you could have a system where other users than root have access to sysfs.

```
fd = assert(io.open("/sys/...."))
```